# Why is my XML filetype configuration overridding my PHP filetype configuration?

Tags: filetype-php, filetype-xml

I'm using Vundle and have [othree/xml.vim](https://github.com/othree/xml.vim) installed, as well as my own bundle for working with PHP.

My PHP bundle has the following code:

```
if exists('b:did_ftplugin') && 1 == b:did_ftplugin
    finish
endif

" ... various things here.

setlocal iskeyword=$,a-z,A-Z,48-57,_-_
```

However, the `iskeyword` option does NOT contain what I've specified above. If I type `verbose set iskeyword?` I get the following output.

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,58,-
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/xml.vim/ftplugin/xml.vim
```

Disabling the `othree/xml.vim` plugin solves this problem, but I don't understand why it would be executing in the first place, as the file type is `php` and not `xml`.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The PHP filetype loads the HTML filetype; from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/php.vim` (around like 63):

```
runtime! syntax/html.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
```

This is because PHP is layered "on top" of HTML, and you can start/stop with the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

That plugin of yours ships with a [`ftplugin/html.vim`](https://github.com/othree/xml.vim/blob/master/ftplugin/html.vim) file which load the `ftplugin/xml.vim` syntax file.

The only way you can fix this is by resetting the `iskeyword` value from an `autocmd`:

```
augroup fix_php
    autocmd FileType php setlocal iskeyword&vim
augroup end
```

The `iskeyword&vim` will reset it to the default Vim value.

You could also consider creating a bug report on their issue tracker.